# Prevent adding users via gnome-control-center

Tags: gnome, users, user-management, adduser, gnome-control-center

We require users to be added using a special script and therefore adding users via GUI (i.e. `gnome-control-center user-accounts`) should be blocked to prevent someone accidentally not using the script.

Is that possible? Removing `gnome-control-center` entirely is not an option. Ubuntu version is currently 20.04.

Comment: Ehm is adding a user not an admin task? why do you have more than 1 or 2 admins?

Comment: I agree. Would you share the typical reasons why a non-admin user would need to add another user?  Perhaps there is a better path.

Comment: @rinzwind It definitely is an admin task. However, admins might only very rarely have to create new user accounts. And if they only add accounts once or twice a year, they might forget to use the script instead of the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Basic idea is to change polkit policy

edit the file `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.accounts.policy`

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.accounts.policy
```

Edited Content:

```
<action id="org.freedesktop.accounts.user-administration">
.........
.........
.........
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>none</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>none</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>none</allow_active>
    </defaults>
 </action>
```

I have edited 3 lines with `none`

Tested in gnome-shell 3.38.0

[image]

the above is just an idea.. you may dig further to have a localized location of the same file to prevent overwrite in updates..